# Why fast eye movement splits a white LED into the RGB components?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, light-emitting-diodes

I have a "white" LED as the notification light on my phone. When I look at it straight it looks whitish, but when I move my eyes around (or shake my head) I suddenly see glimpses of red and green (and probably blue) lights coming out of there. Why?

Comment: Question: can the notification light on your phone appear colored as well as white?

Comment: @DanielGriscom yes

Comment: Then that's strong evidence that @CuriousOne's answer is correct.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I think it would be the same effect even with a "single multi color device".

Comment: A "single multi color device" consists of red, green and blue LEDs in a single device, with each color separately drivable, which is what @CuriousOne is describing. If your light only showed white, then it might have been a "white" LED, which is a single chip, and would never show separate colors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are most likely three LEDs with different colors in that device which are driven by current pulses of different length and timing to achieve an arbitrary RGB color with the least amount of hardware. The result is that you are seeing a stroboscopic effect when you move your eyes fast enough to resolve the timing of the three colors. This is also known as [persistence of vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision), and the educational channel Veritasium covered it in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcstc1ozczQ), showing it in action.

If it's just a white LED with phosphors illuminated by a blue LED as in the answer by count_to_10, it could be the different phosphorescence times of the phosphors after a short pulse excitation by the one blue LED chip.

In either case the eye movement turns the temporal variation of the color into a spatial variation. While your eye is insensitive to the temporal variation (the designer of the device has chosen the "chopping" frequency just high enough to be invisible), it is quite sensitive to spatial variation. So what you are basically doing is to move different "frames" of the light to different locations on your retina.

Comment: stroboscopic effect is basically "frame dropping". Why shaking my head (while still looking at the light) would cause "frame dropping"?

Comment: @Sparkler try this: in a dark room, focus your eyes on a point about a foot to the left of the phone, then move your eyes rapidly to a point about a foot to the right of it, so that the light passes right through the centre of your vision. You should notice that it leaves a trail across your visual field for a split second, and with a bit of practice you should see that trail broken up into distinct red, green and blue segments, caused by the light changing colour as you moved your eyes across it.

Comment: It might be clearer if you move the light while keeping your eyes still, but then you have to move it really fast. I see this all the time with many different types of light and can even use it to estimate the frequency of the pulses - it always amazes me that other people don't notice it.

Comment: This is the same phenomenon know as "tearing" in EVF (electronic viewfinders) in photographic gear. It is probably the exact same thing --- see http://www.projektor.hu/dlp+szivarvany+demo.html (I do not read Hungarian, but the image is quite telling).

Comment: A video explaining the phenomenon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcstc1ozczQ

Answer (score 0):

If you coat a blue LED   with a phosphor material, some of  the blue light will be changed to red, green and yellow light, (which is intended to be seen as white light) and maybe, and I don't know how this could happen, I admit,  shaking your head might allow you to resolve these components.

> I originally had a biology element to this answer, but CuriousOne's comments above  have brought me back to a physics based explanation, and this edit is to reflect that.